# How would I be able to set the pages title as content from a text file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that needs a dynamically updated title. I have a .txt file that is dynamically updated by another script on my website, and I would like to set the content of that file as the page title (the `<title>` tag). Can somebody help me?

Comment: Look for [fileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you can read the txt file and make à echo later

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php
      $myfile = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
      $content = fgets($myfile);
      fclose($myfile);
    ?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to not send any white-spaces before <!DOCTYPE html>! Remove anything between ?> and <!DOCTYPE html>!

Comment: To prevent XSS, always use htmlspecialchars() when echoing into a html document: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>

Comment: almost worked. it's supposed to come out as "It's world whale day!" but instead its "��It's World Whale Day"

Answer (score 0):

follow the below example, I am not tested it but try it once

```
<?php
   $data = fopen("c:\\folder\\testing.txt", "r");
   $ln_array = [];
   $fp = fopen("testfile.txt", "r");
   while (!feof($fp)) {
       // do stuff to the current line here
       array_push($ln_array, $fp);
   }
   fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: nope, didnt work.